# Unable to retrieve a PHP value from another PHP file using the include command

Tags: php, html, forms

So, yeah, I am a newbie and currently I am spending my whole morning trying to find a way to get a value from a php file into another one.

More specifically, I am trying to create a simple captcha system using mt_rand command. So I put, for example, the following code in the first php file:
form.php

```
<?php
$captcha = mt_rand(10000,99999);?>
```

and including the form.php in the other .php file which is designed to be the image in my form page. In other words, the $captcha variable needs to be used in the form.php file so that the code in the image is the same as the one it is going to be checked in form.php using if statements:
image.php (image.php is an IMAGE using imagepng() and other commands)

```
<?php    
include('form.php');?>
```

So, the whole story is about: the $captcha include a random number ranging from 10000-99999 and after the form submission it is checked in the form.php but it is also included (must be* inlcuded) in the image.php to generate the image with the code inside it.

Even though, using the include() command didnt work for me.

I am willing to get a solution in PHP but any others are welcome too, of course.

NOTE: Wanna point that I tried to just generate a random number in the image.php to see if it can be generated and it works ok but it can't retrieve the value when I use the include command.

PS: I guess I am typing too much shit also (too big text, etc), that's because Im really confused right now.

So, If anyone has time to check the two PHP files throughly, here they are:

form.php

```
       <?php 
    $captcha = mt_rand(10000,99999);


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if($_POST['response']=$captcha){
            echo "Captcha verified successfully.";
        }else{
            echo "Wrong Captcha Input!!!</br>";
        }
        }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>Report Cheater</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="" method="post"></textarea><br>
    Captcha(*): <img src="image.php">
    <br><input type="text" name="response"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

image.php

```
<?php
//CAPTCHA verification
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
//Image to be converted into captcha
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(180, 40);

//Captch Background
$im2 = 'capback.png';

//Creates an instance of the captcha background to be added to the captcha
$rsc = imagecreatefrompng($im2);

// Copy and merge
imagecopymerge($im, $rsc, 0, 0, 0, 0, 180, 40, 100);


//Colors to be used
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

//The captcha random number taken directly from report.php
include("form.php"); //works with $captcha = mt_rand(10000,99999); but not with the include("form.php");

// Font
$font = 'arial.ttf';

$x1 = mt_rand(29,41);
$y1 = mt_rand(42,58);
$x2 = $x1 + 1;
$y2 = $y1 + 1;

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, $y2, $x2, $grey, $font, $captcha);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, $y1, $x1, $black, $font, $captcha);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
imagedestroy($rsc);
?>
```

Comment: what kind of error you faced? have you tried `if($_POST['response']==$captcha)`

Comment: i did, just that when I just try to include form.php in image.php, the image just doesn't get generated and I guess it's because it can't retrieve the value.

oh wait, i just need some way to only get the variable I need. Using include command is like getting the whole script and maybe this is what causes the bug.

Comment: Have you tried `die(var_dump($captcha))` just after `include("form.php")` to check the value of `$captcha` variable?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I got my answer already. Mohade's answer worked.. just didn't know how to initiate a session and what's use of it, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you must understand how  capatcha system work

when you generate a hash or random numbers to use in capatcha
you must save it in the user session then use it in image and match it with user input.

In your code you generate two different numbers one in the image and then generated another one when you checked user input and this is logical error.

in image.php :

generate random number and you must start your file with session_start();

```
$capatcha=random(0,1000);
$_SESSION["capatcha"]=$capatcha;
```

then use $_SESSION["capatcha"] to generate image and then use it to verify user input

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if($_POST['response']==$_SESSION["capatcha"]){
            echo "Captcha verified successfully.";
        }else{
            echo "Wrong Captcha Input!!!</br>";
        }
        }
```

Comment: then how do I make your words come true? I mean how can I store this in the user session?

Comment: You can save data for a user in `$_SESSION["yourvalue"]`. To initialize this you have to call `session_start()` before you handle the request (just put this line on top of you .php file). Read more here: http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: try it now and if you want anything else reply here

Comment: 1) You made the mistake of writing "capatcha" instead of "captcha" and I felt I did something wrong again, at least I spotted it :D
2) so the image is generated correctly using the session command u mentioned. But, the form.php is still giving the "wrong captcha input" because seems like it is unable to get thge $_SESSION["captcha"] to verify it.. or i dont know what.
EDIT: oh ye, it is unable to find that variable: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\Wamp\www\captcha\form.php on line 5.

Comment: you must add session_start() at first off all file you want to use session on it , try to add session_start() in  form,php file

Comment: oh, thank you very much. At first, I thought I had to add it only in image.php. Adding it in form.php worked perfectly well. Again thank you man.

Answer (score 3):

You compare two variables with `==`
So change

```
 if($_POST['response']=$captcha){
```

to

```
 if($_POST['response']==$captcha){
```